# Android IllegalArgumentException for dismissDialog

Tags: android, dialog, dismiss, illegalargumentexception

I have used following code for download some files from our internet.

```
public class SplashDownload extends Activity {

    public static final int PROGRESS_DIALOG = 0;
    private ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;
    private WordDataHelper wordDataHelper;
    private ExtraDataHelper extraDataHelper;

    // put your file path here
    private String filePath = "http://test.com/Assets/";
    // put your filename here
    private String fileName;
    // put your download directory name here
    private String downloadDir;

    private int wordCounter = 0, extraCounter = 0, counter = 1;

    private boolean wordDLOn = true;
    private int totalFileNo;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.splashdllayout);
        getDownloadList();
    }

    private void goForward() {

        Intent intent = new Intent().setClass(this, LangH.class)
                .addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }

    private void doNext() {

        if (wordDLOn) {

            System.out.print("wordDetails update: "
                    + wordDetails[wordCounter - 1][0]
                    + extraDetails[extraCounter][0] + fileName);
            wordDataHelper.updateDLStat(Long
                    .valueOf(wordDetails[wordCounter - 1][0]));
        } else {

            System.out.print("extraDetails update: "
                    + extraDetails[extraCounter - 1][0] + fileName);
            extraDataHelper.updateDLStat(Long
                    .valueOf(extraDetails[extraCounter - 1][0]));
        }

        if (wordCounter < wordDetails.length) {
            System.out.print("wordCounter: " + wordCounter + "/"
                    + wordDetails.length);
            startDownload(wordDetails[wordCounter][1]);
            wordCounter++;
        } else if (extraCounter < extraDetails.length) {
            wordDLOn = false;
            downloadDir = "LanH/extras";
            System.out.print("extraCounter: " + extraCounter + "/"
                    + extraDetails.length);
            startDownload(extraDetails[extraCounter][1]);
            extraCounter++;
        } else {
            goForward();
        }
    }

    private void getDownloadList() {

        // lessons download..........

        String[] wordDetails = {"1.mp4","2.mp4","3.mp4","4.mp4","5.mp4","6.mp4","7.mp4","8.mp4",};
        downloadDir = "LanH/words";


        String[] extraDetails = {"a.mp4","b.mp4","c.mp4","d.mp4","e.mp4","f.mp4","g.mp4","h.mp4",};


        totalFileNo = extraDetails.length + wordDetails.length;

        if (wordDetails.length != 0) {
            startDownload(wordDetails[wordCounter]);
            wordCounter++;
        } else if (extraDetails.length != 0) {
            wordDLOn = false;
            startDownload(extraDetails[extraCounter]);
            extraCounter++;
        } else {
            goForward();
        }

    }

    private void startDownload(String dlFilename) {
        // tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv1);
        fileName = dlFilename;
        System.out.print("fileName: " + fileName);

        File dir = new File(android.os.Environment
                .getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()
                + "/"
                + downloadDir);
        // creates the directory if it doesn't exists
        if (dir.exists() == false) {
            dir.mkdirs();
        }
        dir = null;

        if (checkNet()) {
            if (checkExternalMedia() == true) {
                String url = filePath + fileName;
                new DownloadFileAsync().execute(url, fileName);
                mProgressDialog.setMessage("Downloading file.." + fileName);
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "External Media is NOT readable/writable",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        } else {

            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            builder.setMessage("No Internet Connectivity. Check the connection and retry the app.")
                    .setCancelable(false)
                    .setPositiveButton("OK",
                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                int id) {
                            finish();
                        }
                    });
            AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
            alert.show();
        }
    }


    /** Method to check whether external media available and writable. */
    private boolean checkExternalMedia() {
        boolean stat;
        String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();

        if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state)) {
            // Can read and write the media
            stat = true;
        } else if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED_READ_ONLY.equals(state)) {
            // Can only read the media
            stat = false;
        } else {
            // Can't read or write
            stat = false;
        }
        return stat;
    }

    @Override
    protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
        switch (id) {
        case PROGRESS_DIALOG:
            mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
            mProgressDialog.setMessage("Downloading file.." + fileName);
            mProgressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
            mProgressDialog.setCancelable(false);
            mProgressDialog.show();
            return mProgressDialog;
        default:
            return null;
        }
    }

    class DownloadFileAsync extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            showDialog(PROGRESS_DIALOG);
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... aurl) {
            int count;

            try {
                URL url = new URL(aurl[0]);
                URLConnection conexion = url.openConnection();
                conexion.connect();

                int lenghtOfFile = conexion.getContentLength();
                Log.d("DOWNLOAD_TEST", "Lenght of file: " + lenghtOfFile);

                InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream());
                OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(
                        android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                                + "/" + downloadDir + "/" + aurl[1]);

                byte data[] = new byte[1024];

                long total = 0;

                while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
                    total += count;
                    publishProgress("" + (int) ((total * 100) / lenghtOfFile));
                    output.write(data, 0, count);
                }

                output.flush();
                output.close();
                input.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
            return null;

        }

        protected void onProgressUpdate(String... progress) {
            Log.d("DOWNLOAD_TEST", progress[0]);
            mProgressDialog.setProgress(Integer.parseInt(progress[0]));
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String unused) { 

            dismissDialog(PROGRESS_DIALOG);

            // tv.append("\n\nFile Download Complete!");
            // Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn1);
            // btn.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            // you can call a second intent here to redirect to another screen
            doNext();
        }
    }

    private boolean checkNet() {
        boolean connected = false;
        ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        if (connectivityManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE)
                .getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED
                || connectivityManager.getNetworkInfo(
                        ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI).getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED) {
            // we are connected to a network
            connected = true;
        } else
            connected = false;
        return connected;

    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();

    }
}
```

The process is running fine. It is reported following crash report:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: no dialog with id 0 was ever shown via Activity#showDialog
at android.app.Activity.missingDialog(Activity.java:2663)
at android.app.Activity.dismissDialog(Activity.java:2648)
at com.langhost.main.SplashDownload$DownloadFileAsync.onPostExecute(SplashDownload.java:264)
at com.langhost.main.SplashDownload$DownloadFileAsync.onPostExecute(SplashDownload.java:1)
at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:417)
at android.os.AsyncTask.access$300(AsyncTask.java:127)
at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:429)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:143)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5068)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

What is the problem in my code? Is `isShowing()` check before `dismissDialog` will solve the prob?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Does your progress dialog actually show up? 
Instead of dismissing it you could try using `removeDialog(PROGRESS_DIALOG);` to have it cleaned up.

Answer (score 3):

See if this thread helps - [AlerDialog is not created - java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Activity#onCreateDialog did not create a dialog for id X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2733750/alerdialog-is-not-created-java-lang-illegalargumentexception-activityoncreate)

Answer (score 3):

When you do the

```
mProgressDialog.show();
```

during

```
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id)
```

you already set the ID for the Dialog to some random or null value.
So when you call to dismiss it, the Application thinks you are crazy.